# How do I create dynamic classes within a Factory class with variable input parameters?

Tags: php, class

> *Let me know if you have a better title for this question :)*

Up till now, I've created my factory class by doing this:

```php
include_once('menu.class.php');
include_once('gallery.class.php');

class Factory {
  function new_menu_obj() { return new Menu(Conn::get_conn()); }
  function new_gallery_obj($type ='', $id='') { return new Gallery(Conn::get_conn(), $type, $id); }
  /* Many more defined functions here */
}

class Conn { // DB connection }

// To create a new class object I just do this
$menu = Factory::new_menu_obj();
$gallery= Factory::new_gallery_obj('some-type','3');
```

Now I'm trying to do this more dynamically by using this code:

```php
include_once('menu.class.php');
include_once('gallery.class.php');

class Factory {

  private $db_conn;

  private function __construct() {
    $this->db_conn = Conn::get_conn();
  }

  public function create( $class_name ) {
    if ( $this->db_conn === null ) {
      $this->db_conn = Conn::get_conn();
    }
    return new $class_name( $this->db_conn );
  }    
}

class Conn { // DB connection }

// To create a new class object I just do this
$menu = Factory->create("Menu");
$gallery= Factory->create("Gallery"); // How do I pass more parameters here?
```

Is this the "correct way" of being efficient? :)
How can I create a  new object passing variables when I do not know how many variables needs to be passed? Using a array?

Comment: You create _instances_, not classes : ))

Comment: You can use `func_get_args()` in your `create()` method and shift the array so "Menu" or "Gallery" drops out. And then use `call_user_func_array()` to call the constructor of the class and give the shifted array as params array. That workds because you can call a method with more params then args are defined for it.

Comment: @moonwave99 You can dynamically create classes as well

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1 - **Factory->anything** will fail, I guess you mean **Factory::something** in your code. Anyway, with a *private* constructor, you won't be able to create any instance of the Factory class outside of some **static** Factory method...

2 - since you use static methods, use the **static** keyword in your function declaration should be wise.

3 - as a side and personnal note, I'm not sure why you would want to do that. The first flavour of your class does a real [factory](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Factory_method_pattern) job : it creates a consistent set of classes. And you will use another flavour of factory to create another set of similar but still consistent classes.

E.g. the *Factory* class creates *Menu* and *Gallery* instances, the *AltFactory* class creates *AltMenu* and *AltGallery* instances and so on.

But you loose this benefit with the second version of your factory. Just calling the **new** operator on your classes instead of calling your *create* construct will give you exactly the same degree of dependencies, so...

Comment: 1 - Yeah I know. Typo. I created a `global $factory` and then `$factory->create('SomeClass')`. As for the rest of your comments, I really can't comment because this type of "understanding" of factory and classes is beyond my skills at the moment :)

Answer (score 1):

Using reflection and adding a `$params` parameter to your `create` method:

```
class Factory {

  private $db_conn;

  private function __construct() {
    $this->db_conn = Conn::get_conn();
  }

  public function create( $class_name, $params = []) {
    if ( $this->db_conn === null ) {
      $this->db_conn = Conn::get_conn();
    }

    array_unshift($params, $this->db_conn);

    $reflect  = new ReflectionClass($class_name);
    return $reflect->newInstanceArgs($params);    

  }    
}

class Conn { // DB connection }

$menu = Factory->create("Menu");
$gallery= Factory->create("Gallery", ['pics' => ... ])
```

Comment: `$args` is undefined, maybe change it to `$params` .. ?

Comment: Thanks @moonwave99. Previously I've called static functions `$menu = Factory::new_menu_obj();`. Is there a way to continue this?

Comment: PS. This function works great. But an old colleague points out that @herode has some valid arguments, so I think I'll stick with the old code :)